# Programatically unpublish a document in Doc Library in Visual Studio in SharePoint 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepointdocumentlibrary

I'm copying a document from one doc library to another library as a New Version. It's working fine and Publishing the copied document in the destination library.

Is there a way to either copy it unpublished, or add a step to unpublish the current copied document?

Answer (score 0):

Try to change "Moderation status" field (_ModerationStatus) of the new document to SPModerationStatusType.Draft

This can help

Answer (score 0):

Try Somethinbg like this

Where Source file is your document name

> sourceFile.Item.ModerationInformation.Status

set it to draft as 
sourceFile.Item.ModerationInformation.Status = SPModerationStatusType.Draft

Hope this helps